# CXX0030 ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение

Tags: winapi, directx, c++

```
((*(IUnknown*)(&(*(IDirect3DResource9*)(&*vb))))).__vfptr
```

__vfptr CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение

WTF!? Help me please!]

```
dev->CreateVertexBuffer( 4, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
    D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &vb, NULL);
```

При дебаге на этом методе застревает. Пишет это:

> Необработанное исключение в "0x002c1602" в "tutorial.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000000".

```
IDirect3D9* d3d = NULL;
IDirect3DDevice9* dev = NULL;
IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* vb = NULL;
d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS pp;
ZeroMemory(&pp,sizeof(pp));
//тут заполнение pp

d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_REF,hWnd,
                  D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                  &pp, &dev);

dev->CreateVertexBuffer( 4, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY,
                         D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
                         &vb, NULL);
```

Comment: а можно побольше кода, не скупитесь

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: `((*(IUnknown*)(&(*(IDirect3DResource9*)(&*vb))))).__vfptr`

А что могут означать эти амперсанды? Я, конечно, понимаю, что в виндах всё не как у людей, но не настолько же. Что они могут значить? (Желательно словами)

Comment: CreateDevice() нормально завершился? В dev не NULL?

Если ОК, то какой результат CreateVertexBuffer()?

Comment: alexlz, амперсанд по-сути оператор взятия адреса переменной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все разобрался! Проблема, оказывается очень просто решается. Причем я обратил внимание на этот участок кода, когда читал урок, из которого взял этот код. В общем:

```
d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
 D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
 hWnd,
 D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
 &pp, &dev);
```

Так вот, у меня было `D3DDEVTYPE_REF`, заменил на    `D3DDEVTYPE_HAL`

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что вы указали слишком маленький размер буфера, после чего пытаетесь писать за его пределы. Попробуйте написать не

```
dev->CreateVertexBuffer( 4 .....
```

а что-нибудь вроде

```
dev->CreateVertexBuffer(4*sizeof(Vertex) ....
```

Comment: ой, извиняюсь. Когда код скидывал, случайно стер это выражение... 
когда пишешь 4*sizeof(Vertex), или 6*sizeof(Vertex), все та же фигня

Comment: согласен надо пересмотреть функцию на которой вылетает.

Comment: да вроде все правильно указано. Разные примеры пробовал.

Comment: посмотрите что возвращают эта и предыдущие функции. для этого есть макросы FAILED(функция) и SUCCEEDED(функция)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример, как использовать эти макросы. Попробовал сам - ничего не получается.

Comment: например

if (SUCCEEDED(d3d->CreateDevice(...))) // если успешно идем дальше

   if (SUCCEEDED(dev->CreateVertexBuffer(...)))// если успешно идем дальше